# Display images in mysqli php. The image breaks

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
require_once("db.php");
$studentid = SapDB::getInstance()->get_student_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);
 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM file where student_id = $studentid"))
    {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
    while($image = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <div style="width:200px ; height: 200px ; border:1px dashed red ; display:inline-block ; margin-top:5px ; margin-left:5px" class="postedBy">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['image']; ?>">
    </div><!--end image-->
    <?php
    }
}
}
?>
```

As you can see, im trying to display files from my mysql database using php. The code works but my file wont display properly. The image breaks. Please help.

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: Are you posting binary data or Base 64? There's a big difference bewteen them

Comment: i did not encode it as a base 64. Just as plain file